# This "if else" statement don't work in my socket.io/Node.js environment

Tags: node.js, multithreading, if-statement, for-loop, socket.io

So I am developing a simple game. The logic flow is when 2 players connect to the room, the game will initialize and emit a 3 seconds countdown event alongside with a button . if one player clicks the button, that player will emit an event making him/her the host of the game.

The button will appear for 3 seconds. If it disappear without being clicked, the server will randomly pick the host.

Whether or not the button is clicked,after 3 seconds all clients will emit a "ready" event.

Here is my code.

if the button is clicked, the "host" event will be emitted by the client,and my server side code is

```
client.on('host',function(){

   var player = room.getPlayer(client.id);
   player.isHost=true;


 });
```

Then here is the server side for the "ready" event.

```
 client.on("ready", function() {
  var player = room.getPlayer(client.id);
  var table = room.getTable(player.tableID);
   if (2>1) {
      for (var i = 0; i < table.players.length; i++) { 

        if (table.players[i].isHost===true){

          console.log("you are the host")
        } else {
          console.log("we are going to randomly pick a host")
          }

       }
     }
 })
```

Now if no players click the button the terminal will show

we are going to randomly pick a host

we are going to randomly pick a host

we are going to randomly pick a host

we are going to randomly pick a host

Otherwise it will be like

we are going to randomly pick a host

you are the host

we are going to randomly pick a host

you are the host

At this stage only 2 clients are allow for the game so the players.length is 2.It seems like the if/else will be executed same time as the players.length?

Comment: Could it possibly be because you are comparing booleans with `===` which compares value and type?

Comment: the `if/else` will run `table.players.length` times -which seems to be `4` in your case

Comment: I dont see the need for you to run a loop, each player will get its own "you are a host" message

Answer (score 0):

I think the first thing to mention is that the `if (2>1) { ...` is completely unnecessary. The code will simply go through to the for loop as if it's not there.

Your code besides the if statement, is honestly ok. There's nothing that screams 'I cause more loops then necessary'. At this point I would suggest posting anything in the project related to:

1. Multithreading
2. Socket Handling / connecting the socket outside of this

I believe more information is due.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the helps. Yes the for loop is not necessary and it is the cause of the problem. My solution is to detach it from the if-else statement.

```
for (var i = 0; i < table.players.length; i++) { 
}
//test if Host exit in the table
 if (table.ifHost===true){

      console.log("you are the host")
    } else {
      var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * table.playerLimit);

       var Host=table.players[randomNumber]
      }
```

The interesting thing I found out about the socket io is when two sockets fire this event, if Host doesn't exit,the first one will execute the else(noHost) and then create a Host. The second socket will execute the if condition as the host was created by the previous socket....